# Accessing a .docx file's XML programatically?

Tags: c#, .net

If you take a `.docx` file, rename it to `.zip`, and unzip it, you can view its `.xml` files. I'm building a program to programmatically inspect these XML properties (no existing API seems to suffice as our company is using a 3rd party program that attaches custom XML to files, and that program does not have an API).

Is there a clean way to access this XML without programmatically saving copies of files as `.zip` files, opening them, taking out only the XML and then deleting the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [openxml](http://openxmldeveloper.org) sdk to fetch all the xml elements

`WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(this.FilePath, true);
 MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
 List<OpenXmlElement> ParagraphElements = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
 foreach (var i in mainPart.Document.ChildElements.FirstOrDefault().ChildElements)
            {
                ParagraphElements.Add(i);
            }`

Here is your complete solution,
From ParagraphElements all XML elements can be retrieved.
This's easy way to access XML elements present in it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)?

Allows you to access the xml files inside .docx files.